# Updating PHP from 8.0.x to 8.0.28 using dnf

Tags: package-management, php, software-updates

Will this update PHP 8.0.25 to PHP 8.0.28?

```
dnf module reset php
dnf module enable php:remi-8.0
dnf update php\*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, updating PHP using the **dnf** package manager on a system running **PHP 8.0.x** with the following commands will update PHP to version **8.0.28**:

Here's a brief explanation of what each of the commands does:

1. **dnf module reset php**: This command resets the PHP module to its default state. This is useful to ensure that you are starting from a clean slate when updating PHP.
2. **dnf module enable php:remi-8.0**: This command enables the Remi repository, which contains the latest version of PHP 8.0.x.
3. **dnf update php***: This command updates all packages with "php" in their name to the latest version available in the enabled repositories.

Here are the commands in context:

```
$ sudo dnf module reset php
$ sudo dnf module enable php:remi-8.0
$ sudo dnf update php\*
```

After running these commands, your system's PHP version should be updated to the latest version available in the **Remi repository (currently 8.0.28)**.

Comment: Yes, but the reset / enable is usually not required. When used once to install, a simple "dnf update" is enough.

Comment: Also, cherry-picking updates (only "php" in this case), is usually a bad idea, and not really supported.